# ModuleNotFoundError when importing a module that again imports another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

My directory structure:

```
test/
    algo/
        base.py
        func.py
    main.py
```

`func.py` import `base`, and `main.py` import `func`. The scripts are:

```py
# base.py

def base():
    pass
```

```py
# func.py

from base import base
def func():
    base()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   func()
```

```py
# main.py 

from algo.func import func 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   func()
```

when I execute `func.py`, it is fine:

```
cd test/algo
python func.py # OK
```

But when run `main.py` if fails:

```
cd test
python main.py # => ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "base"
```

Now if I add `.` prefix for `base` in `func.py`:

```py
from .base import base # add dot prefix here
def func():
    base()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   func()
```

This time, run `main.py` is OK, but run `func.py` results in error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.base'; '__main__' is not a package`

Why this ?

And what is the right way to import `base` in `func`, so that `func` could be executed directly, and be imported by `main`?

Thanks!

My environment: MacOS, python3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you consider `algo/` as a Python Package, in this case you can use:

```py
# func.py
from algo.base import base
```

Why does it works? It's because the Python interpreter adds the executed file directory in its module search path (`sys.path`). So Python sees an `algo/` directory under it, making `import algo` and friends work.

Now if you want to run `func.py` directly you're having an issue: the `algo/` directory is no longer discoverable from `sys.path` and you're hitting the import error, while your code is right.

The proper way to make this work is to tell Python how to find your package.

The quick-and-dirty way is to use PYTHONPATH to add the directory containing your package to `sys.path`:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python3 algo/func.py
```

The clean way to do it will appear later: if you properly package your project (by adding a `pyproject.toml` and a `setup.cfg` to it for example see https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), then you'll be able to install your package:

```
pip install .
```

"installing" means "putting the package in a place Python expect it", so obviously, once installed, all `import algo` will work, without modifying PYTHONPATH, and dependless on your current working directory.

Last word, you should place an empty `__init__.py` file in your `algo/` folder to make it a proper Python package, without it it's a `Python namespace package`, something a bit different, not what you really want.

And and, have you heard about `__main__.py`? It's the namespace executed when your run `python3 -m YOUR_PACKAGE` (`python3 -m algo` in your example).